# Получение системного имени пользователя

Tags: аутентификация, ldap, php, firefox, linux

Есть Linux-сервер и несколько рабочих станций, тоже линуксовых. Для аутентификации пользователей используется LDAP. Рабочий браузер - Firefox. Каким образом веб-приложение может узнать имя пользователя? getenv(), $_SERVER(['REMOTE_USER']) по умолчанию ничего не возвращают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

во, нашел, поидее после успешной аутентификации через mod_ldap логин и пароль ббудет содержаться в переменных

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']
```

[пруф](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239069/how-do-i-retrieve-the-user-information-of-a-user-authenticated-with-apaches-mod) ответа и еще один вариант там же

просто в противному случае это был бы бред, если бы нельзя было бы через лдап авторизацию делать.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

А ауиентификация происходит средствами веб-сервера (mod_ldap_authz, к примеру)? или php? Если средствами сервера, то думаю, никак. Если скрипта, то все просто - если биндинг к лдап удался, то у вас есть и логин и пасс..

Comment: В том-то и дело, что средствами сервера.

Завис над второй частью ответа. Как связаться с LDAP, имея логин и пароль, я знаю. А как можно узнать логин и пароль, имея только соединение - не понял. Можно поподробнее?

Comment: Я же говорю, если авторизация средствами сервера (его модулями), то в ваш код никак не попадет логин\пасс

Comment: теоретически через установку переменных окружения вебсервера... но это теория...

Comment: @thunder это сильно теория, т.к. сервер работает в своем окружении, которое совсем не пересекается с работой php

Comment: см. ответ ;)